# Is there any way to detect adjacent circles in image using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to detect adjacent circles in an image. these can be either 4 or 5. is there any way to detect it in opencv. i tried many ways, including hough circles method. but i am detecing extra circles too. if in any case i am able to detect circle than same parameters won't work with other images.

Please let me know of any thing possible to achieve this.

My code using Hough Circles is:

```
Mat img, gray;
img = imread("/Users/Development/Desktop/Images/IMG_0297.jpg");
cvtColor(img, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
// smooth it, otherwise a lot of false circles may be detected
GaussianBlur( gray, gray, Size(9, 9), 2, 2 );
vector<Vec3f> circles;
HoughCircles(gray, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2, gray.rows/16,80,100,30,50 );
for( size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++ )
{
    Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
    int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
    // draw the circle center
    circle( img, center, 3, Scalar(0,255,0), -1, 8, 0 );
    // draw the circle outline
    circle( img, center, radius, Scalar(0,0,255), 3, 8, 0 );
}
namedWindow( "circles", 1 );
imshow( "circles", img );
waitKey(0);
return 0;
```

sample image is 
[image]

and i want to detect dials in this, that are adjacent to eachother

Answer (score 4):

You can use [partition](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/clustering.html#partition) to cluster circles adjacent circles, i.e. circles whose center distance is similar to the sim of their radii. You just need to define the appropriate *equivalence* predicate, here implemented in `CirclesOnSameLine`. You can eventually improve this predicate to consider as equal only circles that have similar radius.

The result of this clustering is something like (same color means same cluster):

[image]

With this approach, you can safely detect some circle, since you can then remove circles that don't belong to clusters with more than 4-5 circles.

[image]

Code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

struct CirclesOnSameLine
{
    float _tolerance;

    CirclesOnSameLine(float tolerance) : _tolerance(tolerance) {};

    bool operator()(const Vec3f& lhs, const Vec3f& rhs)
    {
        // [0] = x
        // [1] = y
        // [2] = radius
        float center_distance = sqrt((lhs[0] - rhs[0])*(lhs[0] - rhs[0]) + (lhs[1] - rhs[1])*(lhs[1] - rhs[1]));
        float sum_radii = lhs[2] + rhs[2];

        if (sum_radii > center_distance)
        {
            return (sum_radii / center_distance) < _tolerance;
        }
        return (center_distance / sum_radii) < _tolerance;
    }
};


int main()
{
    Mat3b img = imread("path_to_image");

    Mat1b gray;
    cvtColor(img, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    GaussianBlur(gray, gray, Size(9, 9), 2, 2);
    vector<Vec3f> circles;
    HoughCircles(gray, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2, gray.rows / 16, 80, 100, 10, 100);

    // Cluster circles near each other
    vector<int> labels;
    int n_labels = partition(circles, labels, CirclesOnSameLine(1.1f));

    vector<Scalar> colors;
    for (int i = 0; i < n_labels; ++i)
    {
        Scalar color(rand() & 255, rand() & 255, rand() & 255);
        colors.push_back(color);
    }

    Mat3b adjacent = img.clone();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++)
    {
        Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
        int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
        // draw the circle outline
        circle(adjacent, center, radius, colors[labels[i]], 3, 8, 0);
    }

    // Remove small clusters
    vector<int> count(labels.size(), 0);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < labels.size(); ++i)
    {
        count[labels[i]]++;
    }

    Mat3b big_clusters = img.clone();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++)
    {
        if (count[labels[i]] < 4) continue;

        Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
        int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
        // draw the circle outline
        circle(big_clusters, center, radius, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3, 8, 0);
    }



    imshow("Adjacent circles", adjacent);
    imshow("Adjacent circles", big_clusters);

    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could chamfer match the circles for example and then check if the circle shares an edge with another circle or is close to it using edge detection and a scan of the image to see if the circles are close enough to be adjacent or not.

With this specific image you could probably do kmeans and connected components. Then chamfer match circles and see if a connected component is made up of multiple circles.

Comment: chamfer matching is not supported with opencv. here is the reference http://code.opencv.org/issues/3602